# QGIS 2.12.1 crashes on Mac OSX-11 because of Incompatible PROJ library version

Tags: qgis, osx

I have just installed QGIS 2.12.1 on my mac OSX-11 El Capitan and all relevant libraries - on running QGIS and loading a previous project the program shuts down.
The error reported is:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Versions/4/PROJ
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
  Reason: Incompatible library version: QGIS requires version 11.0.0 or later, but PROJ provides version 10.0.0
```

Comment: download the last version of the [Proj Framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks-)

Comment: Thanks underdark downloaded and installed. Opening projects works, saves in v2.12 but on exit I get another error report, however on reopen all data seems to be OK.